# Change a CSS style of Raphael text with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I can change a CSS attribute of a Raphael text with jQuery like so:

```
var text = paper.text(10,10,'abc');
$(text.node).css('font-style','italic');
```

How can I do the same with just javascript and no jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, use `element.style.property = 'new-style';` to edit styles of an element.

```
var text = paper.text(10,10,'abc');
text.node.style.fontStyle = 'italic';
```

Comment: you mean fontStyle, not font-style

Comment: @paddyfields Fixed :)

Comment: @Run_Script will that work with a Raphael text object?

Comment: @ps0604 It should do. If it doesn't work for you, try `text.node.style.fontStyle = 'italic';`

Comment: @Run_Script it worked with `text.node`, you should change the answer

Comment: @ps0604 Ok, I've updated the answer! Glad it worked :)